# No module named 'cog' discordpy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm getting this error message when trying to load cogs:

> parent = **import**(parent_name, fromlist=['**path**'])
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cog'

Code:

```
COGS = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./cogs/*.py")]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)

for cog in COGS:
    print(f"loading cog... {cog}")
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{cog}")
```

[image]

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: `COGS = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./cogs/*.py")` Here do you want to search for .py files in current directory or parent?

Comment: I actually figure it out! I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out so hopefully this will help someone with this issue.

For Windows, the directory separator is 2 back slashes. But for Linux, 1 forward slash.

So, I change this line from this:

```
COGS = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./cogs/*.py")]
```

To this:

```
COGS = [path.split("/")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./cogs/*.py")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you figured it out, but if you want your code to work on any platform, and save yourself the hassle of specifying separators and slices, you could use Python's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which makes a lot of things [cleaner and more convenient](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/).

```
from pathlib import Path

cogs = [path.stem for path in Path('cogs').glob('*.py')]
```

- `Path('cogs')` (or, equivalently, `Path('./cogs')` ), creates a Path object representing your cogs folder.
- This Path object has a `glob` method that returns Path objects representing each matching file. (Note: you don't need to import the `glob` module for this; it's part of the Path object.)
- Path objects have handy attributes like `name` (`'cog.py'`), `extension` (`'.py'`), and `stem` (`'cog'`).

`pathlib` is several years old at this point (2014), and included in the standard Python distribution, but a lot of tutorials and recipes out there haven't yet caught up. It can make your code remarkably cleaner, more portable, and easier to modify.

(In particular, you always specify paths to `Path()` with forward slashes, and it automatically handles the necessary separator conversion for different platforms.)